# How to find battery leak in my application?

Tags: java, android, optimization, android-gps

I've written an application, it's a big one and it has lots of features.

But I have a problem with it: in the phone battery usage it takes about 35 percent of battery and it's a huge problem even when I don't use it very much.

I've no services in my application and I really don't know where the problem is.

Is there any way that I can find out what is using my battery?

Comment: using location ?

Comment: @Redman yes I'm using location

Comment: Check out for code that runs often, causes the radio to start up and/or does long computations.

Comment: Having location listener will cause battery drain , start location updates only when needed , and stop them when you don't .

Comment: Here's a list of best practices when optimizing battery usage for location updates: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/battery

Answer (score 1):

I am using [PowerTutor](http://ziyang.eecs.umich.edu/projects/powertutor/) for this purpose when i am testing my application performance and battery usage. Even i am using this application also https://developer.qualcomm.com/software/trepn-power-profiler. Please try this let me know if it helps you.